# Reading a large file in perl, record by record, with a dynamic record separator

Tags: perl, performance, file-io

I have a script that reads a large file line by line.  The record separator (`$/`) that I would like to use is (`\n`).  The only problem is that the data on each line contains CRLF characters (`\r\n`), which the program should not be considered the end of a line.

For example, here is a sample data file (with the newlines and CRLFs written out):

```
line1contents\n
line2contents\n
line3\r\ncontents\n
line4contents\n
```

If I set `$/ = "\n"`, then it splits the third line into two lines.  Ideally, I could just set `$/` to a regex that matches `\n` and not `\r\n`, but I don't think that's possible.  Another possibility is to read in the whole file, then use the split function to split on said regex.  The only problem is that the file is too large to load into memory.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this particular task, it sounds pretty straightforward to check your line ending and append the next line as necessary:

```
$/ = "\n";
...
while(<$input>) {
    while( substr($_,-2) eq "\r\n" ) {
        $_ .= <$input>;
    }
    ...
}
```

This is the same logic used to support [line continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_continuation#Line_continuation) in a number of different programming contexts.

You are right that you can't set `$/` to a regular expression.

Comment: +1: This is the only suggestion so far that will work on the data as given.  Conversion with 'dos2unix' will destroy the structure of the file completely, and converting '\r\n' to space, tab or something is probably hard to reverse - you have to choose a replacement that cannot appear in the main text of the lines.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very straightforward approach that I can't believe I didn't think of.  This could even be applied to a more general case where the pattern is more complex.

Answer (score 1):

dos2unix would put a UNIX newline character in for the "\r\n" and so wouldn't really solve the problem.  I would use a regex that replaces all instances of "\r\n" with a space or tab character and save the results to a different file (since you don't want to split the line at those points).  Then I would run your script on the new file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [dos2unix](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) on the file first, and then read in as normal.

Comment: From the OP it seems that \r\n is a way to *escape* \n and not a "bad" \n.